# "Only static constant integral variables may be initialized within a class "

Tags: c++, class, variables, static

can someone explain to me why cant i initialize a static variable inside the class ? what happens in compilation time exactly ?

for example :

```
class Object {
    static int numberOfObjects = 0; // This gives the error
    Object(){ 
        nummberOfObjects++;
    }
};
```

Thanks !

Comment: Note that this only applies pre-C++11.

Comment: Please post the code that gave this warning.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

In versions of C++ prior to C++11, the language standard simply doesn't allow you to perform a static variable definition inside the class declaration.  In other words, You can't initialize it because it isn't constant.  Since it can change during execution, the compiler needs some memory allocated somewhere to actually keep the value in.  Since this is a class declaration, it doesn't actually allocate the memory for you.  This issue doesn't exist for const values because they don't need memory assigned -- they are effectively "hard coded" just like if you replaced them with literals (or an old 'C' style #define).

You need a line of code outside of the class declaration that basically says:

```
    int Object::numberOfObjects = 0;
```

This line isn't just initializing the static class variable, it's actually allocating a static int that will be used to store the value.  The line of code up in the class declaration doesn't do this -- it merely tells the compiler that such a value exists somewhere.

Note that starting with C++11 this behavior is different.  The language is now smart enough to figure out that you DO want to that memory defined, so you no longer need to do so manually.

Comment: This explanation has a bunch of flaws though. Firstly, it isn't true, as the feature you tried to use can be used with newer C++ versions. Secondly, the explanation is bad, because `inline` functions can be declared multiple times (provided they obey the ODR) and the linker will throw out all but one of them. Further, if you put `std::string x = "abc";`, in a header it will allocate memory for this (but it will violate the ODR if included multiple times, unless made `static` or `const`).

Comment: Those are good points.  It certainly isn't theoretically impossible for the compiler to perform the initialization; rather, the compiler simply didn't behave in this way prior to C++11.  I was trying to supply an intuitive reasoning for why the compiler behaves in that manner -- I did not mean to suggest that it could not behave any other way.  Thanks for the correction!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your point about inline functions.  These aren't quite the same thing as variable definitions, since you aren't reserving memory to write to.  With inlines, you are indeed allowing the compiler to do more of a cut and paste -- again; they closely resemble what might be done with older C preprocessor macros.

Comment: The fact that you can include that definition in a header file is correct, but entirely beside the point.  That line of code would happen to reside in the header file, but it wouldn't be part of the class declaration per se.  Whether it is in a ".c" file or included from a ".h" is purely convention, it makes no difference to the compiler -- indeed, the compiler only sees the post preprocessing input where that line has been added into the source by the #include statement.

Comment: The const values may need memory assigned, for example if you take their address. (The technical term for this is *odr-used*). So your rationale is not correct. In any case it'd be good for your post to clearly demarcate the language rules from the rationale you've added.

Comment: The point about inlining: Let's forget the copy'n'pasting of the function body, which compilers will do on their own anyway. Without that, `inline` only instructs the compiler to ignore what would be ODR violations and instead discard superfluous definitions. There's no reason it couldn't do the same for data. For that, it doesn't matter if that data is at namespace scope, statically inside a function or even statically in a class.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a rule from the standard that was implemented by the compiler. The fact that it was a rule doesn't mean the opposite isn't possible, as the change in the newer C++11 standard and according compilers show.